# Java good practices of which class should go where (packages)

Tags: java, structure

So I'm having this issue. I'm a student and also am working but somehow I was never told or shown how to exactly put classes to packages according to good practices. In my job the project is big, but created long time ago by people who aren't best programmers, so it's all very chaotic. At my university nobody seems to care about this.

I feel like it's very basic thing and yet I'm not entirely sure.
I will ask the question with java in mind, so let's say that I have those classes like `User` class, `UserForm` for changing user data class, `UserController` class, `UserRepository` class and let's say the same classes for something not that related to user, like `Shop`.

How should I put those in the packages? What should the structure be?

Comment: one packed called "model" to contain all data / data-base related classes . personally the rest is at your wish

Comment: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205

Comment: @SrinathGanesh this doesn't seem to be backed up by anything. In fact, your link exactly contradicts your advice.

Comment: Wanted to post the same link, but the question was closed. I recommend package by feature like the above link does.

Comment: I as a student [smaller projects] prefer packages like (model,util....) , but at the same time have seen suggestions of better ways to work [might help on bigger projects] so i made a mention of both in separate comments

Comment: @SrinathGanesh absolutely not! If you start out with a small project this way and they grow over time, you're screwed.